# Trac Multiple Projects - Available Projects Page /path/to/templates error

Tags: trac

I've got two standalone trac projects (two websites)

```
/path/to/project1
/path/to/project2
```

I created a templates folder upstream of the projects since the 
template would apply to, and list all available projects

```
/path/to/templates
```

So, instead of using

```
$ tracd -p 8080 /path/to/project1 /path/to/project2
```

I used

```
$ tracd -p 8080 -e /path/to
```

based on to the Usage examples seen [here](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracStandalone).  This pulls up a page with "Available Projects", and the two project links listed. So far, so good...

I then went to the Usage examples [here](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracInterfaceCustomization) and copied the template under the Project List topic and saved it to `/path/to/templates/projects.html`

Then according to their page I export the path to the Available Projects template

```
$ export TRAC_ENV_INDEX_TEMPLATE=/path/to/templates/projects.html
$ sudo -u myUsername tracd --port=8000 -e /path/to
```

When I pull up `http://localhost:8000` I get the following

```
Available Projects

project1 - Voyage to  Mars
project2 - The Return Trip

templates: Error 2, 'No such file or directory'
```

The paths all are absolute from the root, I'm not sure why trac can't find the template.  Any ideas what I am missing?

Thanks for any help...

Answer (score 0):

I've done the customization before with success. So it can be done.

The only glitch I can spot in your description, that you specify the *template with path*, while [the referenced wiki documentation](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracInterfaceCustomization#ProjectList) suggests to only provide the **path**.

Maybe, you can already succeed with this hint. I'll double-check tomorrow - no access right now.